# "How much English he knows!" Vs "How beautiful it is!"

Tags: usage

When I want to show my enthusiasm or wonder about someone English (for example someone who just started to learn English and he has nice English) then what is the way to that in exclamatory sentence? I thought about "**How much English he knows!**" but when I see "**How beautiful she is!**" I don't see the use in "**much**" while English and beauty are not countable nouns.

So though **English** is a noun and **beautiful** is an adjective, I am not sure if it's Ok to say it in the way that I thought (using "how + much").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to compliment the speaker about.

Your example

> **How much English he knows!**

is correct and might usually be understood to mean the person has a *broad vocabulary*, especially if he is a learner.  If instead you wanted to compliment them on being very conversant, you might say

> **He is a** *(very)* **fluent speaker**.
>   **He speaks like a native**.

If you think they are particularly expressive, as in poetry, you might say

> **His English is beautiful.
>
>   He is well-spoken.**